# How to get value from agg_vec in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, forecast, tsibble, fable

I am working with fpp3 forecasting package in R in order to produce a hierarchical forecast but I only need the forecast of the lower levels. Sadly, all values came in an agg_vec type which is not something I want.
Is there anyway to extract its value?
(source: https://otexts.com/fpp3/single-level.html)

As an example, instead of this

```
Region
<S3: agg_vec>
<S3: agg_vec>
<S3: agg_vec>
```

I would like I column the string/char representing the Region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `format()` the `<agg_vec>` type to convert it to a character, however this will lose the structure for plotting and reconciliation purposes.

If you are trying to see the output using RStudio inline of an R Markdown document, unfortunately there is currently a display issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6878

The correct output should be visible when outputting the table in the console.